# how to convert json array object into csv format and export it in excel file in an ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm a newbie in ionic frameworks, I'm developing an app in which I need to convert the data which is coming from $HTTP.post method, into CSV format and on button click it should download in .xsl format, I already searched so many articles on it but not worked.. please help me... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question here.. 
[Angular.js generate csv file from json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416989/angular-js-generate-csv-file-from-json-data)

If you're using ionic, I would assume angular, and therefore recommend this  directive that turns arrays and objects into downloadable CSV files.

https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv

If you don't want to read the accepted answers. Here's the sklinny.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'])
```

Add ng-csv directive to the wanted element, example:

```
<button type="button" ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
```

In your controller, getarray is just your array (the json you'd get back from your request).

```
 $scope.getArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];
```

Comment: how to add cordovaFile plugin...? I tried but Its showing an error..in injector

Comment: @anjalijibhakate http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/ , Ngcordova plugins work on device.